# How to remove all empty elements from an xml file using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

How can you remove all empty elements from an XML file using C#?

Eg:

Input

```
<Person>
  <PersonDetails>
    <Name>Some Name</Name>
    <Address>
      <Street>Some Street</Street>
      <City>Some City</City>
      <Zip/>
    </Address>
 </PersonDetails>
 <PersonDetails>
    <Name>Some Name</Name>
    <Address/>
 </PersonDetails>
 <PersonDetails/>
</Person>
```

Output

```
<Person>
  <PersonDetails>
    <Name>Some Name</Name>
    <Address>
      <Street>Some Street</Street>
      <City>Some City</City>
    </Address>
 </PersonDetails>
 <PersonDetails>
    <Name>Some Name</Name>
 </PersonDetails>
</Person>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!  No need to "vandalize" your XML, and no need for tons of `<br />` tags - just format it !!

Comment: @marc_s: Cool, never noticed that. I'm always typing four extra spaces, or just indent my code in VS2010 before posting.

Comment: Do you want to recursively remove empty elements from inside out? For example, if all the elements in PersonDetail are empty, do you also want to remove the PersonDetail element?

Answer (score 7):

Based on your updated question, you can just use an XPath one-liner to get what you're after:

```
var doc = XElement.Parse(source);  // or XElement.Load(filename) if coming from a file   

doc.XPathSelectElements("//*[string-length() = 0]").ToList().Remove();

doc.Save(filename)                 // or doc.ToString() if you want the string output
```

If you prefer not to use XPath, you can use `Descendants()` and LINQ:

```
doc.Descendants().ToList().Where(d => d.Value.Length == 0).Remove();
```

The `ToList()` in both cases is necessary to ensure you're not modifying an enumerable in place.

Comment: Thanks this one works. But it not removing empty elements inside an element (hierarchy). I my case i will be getting different xml files with different structure. Is there any way I can remove empty elements from for any type of XML structure?

Comment: you could adapt this answer pretty easily by creating a method, e.g. IsElementEmpty() that recursed through all child elements until it either 1. ran out of child elements or 2. found one with a value.

Comment: @user1432798 I've updated the answer to do what you're looking for.